# What is the difference between Apple's "Safari Technology Preview" for the public and the Safari beta download for developers?

Tags: safari, developer-program, beta, macos

It is my guess that the [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/) (STP) is updated less frequently than the Beta for Developers (BD).

I wonder if Apple publishes an explainer on the differences between the two, apart from the observable update cadence difference, and the marketing to different audiences.

April 15, 2021 - I see that the last BD release was on April 6, 2021. I speculate that STP was last updated in early March 2021 based on the tickets in the [release log](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/).

[Safari download page](https://web.archive.org/web/20210408004756/https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/)